# Laravel Excel Not Importing Data To Database

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

When I am importing data from excel after getting the file and on the step of saving data to db it  showing field doesn't have value from excel file. Where as all the fields are filled with data.

i am using laravel excel

LeadImport Code

```
 return new lead([
        'name'  => $row[0],
        'leadid'  => $row[1],
        'number'   => $row[2],
        'city'  => $row[3],
        'state' => $row[4],
        'address'   => $row[5],
        'pincode'   => $row[6],
        'type'  => $row[7],
        
    ]);

Controller Code
Excel::import(new LeadsImport, $request->file('file'));
```

Error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'leadid' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `leads` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-01-14 19:24:21, 2022-01-14 19:24:21))
```

Comment: Hello please shere all LeadImport Code class

Comment: @mohammadgitipasand
 namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\lead;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

Comment: @miken32 NO that's not using any Excel Module

Comment: This is nothing to do with excel. You’re trying to save something to the database with a missing value.

Comment: @miken32 No bro, I'm saving data using excel. Read title and body of the question

Answer (score 0):

The `leadid` don't have any assigned value and it doesn't have any default value assigned. What is `$row[1]` returning? I assume `row[1]`'s value is null, that's why you actually get this error. `dd()` it and tell us what it returns.

Comment: if i set leadid to null then it showing same error on 'name' column

Comment: `dd($row)` and see if it actually has any value in `row[0]` and `row[1]`. The error is coming from that you are trying to insert `literally nothing` in a table column. Or either to debug it make `name` and `leadid` nullable so you can see if it is actually inserting the other data.

Comment: leadid
name
number 
city 
state 
address 
pincode 
type
1123 vivek 8168501882 bhiwani haryana 221 127021 staff

<<<< above is my data in excel.

It is not print $row showing undefined variable.....

also when i try print $request->file('file') in dd. It showing only file name


and if i make leadid & name column null... then it will showing the same error on another column

Comment: I think the problem is coming from `$request->file('file')`. It's not getting the file correct that's why everything is coming with a `null` error. I had similar problem with the `$request->file` but I can't remember where was the problem. Overall you have a problem with getting the file. Showing only the name of the file when `dd()` means you're not getting the file correct.

Comment: -test: false
  -originalName: "book.xlsx"
  -mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpF2C2.tmp"
  basename: "phpF2C2.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF2C2.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF2C2.tmp"
  size: 8251
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF2C2.tmp"
<<<<<< dd response

Answer (score 0):

in your excel file you must have cells:

```
name, leadid, number, city, state, address, pincode, type
```

and in LeadImport just:

```
 return new lead([
    'name' => $row['name'],
    'leadid' => $row['leadid'],
    'number' => $row['number'],
    'city' => $row['city'],
    'state' => $row['state'],
    'address' => $row['address'],
    'pincode' => $row['pincode'],
    'type' => $row['type'],
    
]);
```

Comment: Thanks For giving you time...... when i am going through this. It's showing this new error 'Undefined index: leadid'